# Isn't there a short formula for the sum of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this sequence:

$$f(n) = f(n-1)a + b$$

The sum of this is:

$$s(n) = f(0)a^n + ba^{n-1} + ba^{n-2} ... + ba^{0}$$

if I am right.

Isn't there a way to write the $ba^{n-1} + ba^{n-2} ... + ba^{0}$ part in a shorter format?

Comment: See [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$f(2)=f(0)a^2+ab+b$$
$$f(3)=f(0)a^3+a^2b+ab+b$$
and so on. So what you are computing isn't the sum of the first $n$ terms, it's the $n$'th term.

Now for the shorthand notation:
$$f(n)=f(0)a^n + b\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^k=f(0)a^n+b\dfrac{a^n-1}{a-1}$$
I used Sigma sum notation and the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is not the sum. I should sleep a few hours and continue. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Sigma Summation Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation).

Using this, you'd have

$$s(n) = f(0) a^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b a^k.$$